# How to hide tab content of all the angular-material tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I need to hide tab body of all the tabs.

```
<md-tabs class="md-accent" md-align-tabs="{{data.bottom ? 'bottom' : 'top'}}" >
      <md-tab md-active="false">
        <md-tab-label>Layer</md-tab-label>
        <md-tab-body class="rightTabBdy">
          tab1
        </md-tab-body>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab md-active="false">
        <md-tab-label>Model</md-tab-label>
        <md-tab-body>
          tab2
        </md-tab-body>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab md-active="false">
        <md-tab-label>Legends</md-tab-label>
        <md-tab-body>
          tab3
        </md-tab-body>
      </md-tab>
 </md-tabs>
```

As per doc, at least one tab should be active always and also ng-hide/ng-show will not work :-(. So I tried by adding one dummy tab, But its not working

```
<md-tab md-active="true" ng-if="someCond==true">>></md-tab>
```

In controller

```
$scope.someCond = false;
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/NaghaveerGowda/94h7aq3x/7/

Anyone can help me in this?

Comment: Can you validate  this one : https://jsfiddle.net/ankitkumar148/94h7aq3x/8/

Comment: @Dreamweaver If I click on the dummy tab still I can see the tab-body :-( I should be able to hide all the tabs body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `md-selected` to some tab index that doesn't exist like `md-selected="-1"` on `<md-tabs>` seems to do it.

```js
var app = angular.module('sandbox', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.someCond = false;
})
```

```css
md-tabs-content-wrapper {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sandbox">
  <md-tabs class="md-accent" md-selected="-1" md-align-tabs="{{data.bottom ? 'bottom' : 'top'}}">
    <!-- this should be a kind of button to close all tabs -->
    <md-tab md-active="true" ng-if="someCond==true">>></md-tab>
    <md-tab md-active="false">
      <md-tab-label>Layer</md-tab-label>
      <md-tab-body class="rightTabBdy">
        tab1
      </md-tab-body>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab md-active="false">
      <md-tab-label>Model</md-tab-label>
      <md-tab-body>
        tab2
      </md-tab-body>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab md-active="false">
      <md-tab-label>Legends</md-tab-label>
      <md-tab-body>
        tab3
      </md-tab-body>
    </md-tab>
  </md-tabs>
</div>
```

### [Updated Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/94h7aq3x/9/)